# Split tensorflow dataset in batches

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets, batchsize

I have a time series dataset of dimensions `[all = 600, time sequence, features]` and I am feeding it to a keras model with the `fit` method.

I am specifying to the method a the batch size =32, but, when the actual training starts, the epoch ends in one go meaning the entire dataset has been fitted without splitting.

I tried splitting it manually but:

1. I need to discard 30 samples which I rather not.
2. The resulting 4 dimensions are not accepted by the model.

How can I force the batch split?

### Edit 1

Showing the code where i call model.fit

```
 train_batches, val_batches = batches
    history = model.fit(
        train_batches,
        epochs=epochs,
        validation_data=val_batches,
        callbacks=callbacks,
        batch_size=batch_size)
```

Where

````
train_batches: <TensorDataset shapes: ((685, 30, 62), (685, 7, 1)), types: (tf.float64, tf.float64)>
val_batches : <TensorDataset shapes: ((189, 30, 62), (189, 7, 1)), types: (tf.float64, tf.float64)>```
````

Comment: Show the piece of your code where you use fit method.

Comment: I edited the post to add the fit method and the relative inputs